# How to avoid wrapping in bc output

Tags: bc

I have the following example in GNU v. 1.06 (I cannot identify a limit pertaining to line length):

```
v=$(bc -l <<<"scale=100;4*a(1)"); echo $v
```

which returns:

```
3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307\ 
8164062862089986280348253421170676
```

Is it possible to remove the backslash and carriage return in this function's output, or am I looking for something that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 9):

At least in GNU `bc`, you can set environment variable `BC_LINE_LENGTH` to a zero value e.g.

```
BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc -l <<<"scale=100;4*a(1)"
```

From `man bc`:

```
BC_LINE_LENGTH
       This should be an integer specifying the number of characters in
       an  output  line  for  numbers.  This includes the backslash and
       newline characters for long numbers.  As an extension, the value
       of  zero  disables  the  multi-line feature.  Any other value of
       this variable that is less than 3 sets the line length to 70.
```

Answer (score 2):

With the GNU implementation of `bc`, starting with version 1.07 you can use `BC_LINE_LENGTH=0` (`DC_LINE_LENGTH=0` for GNU `dc`) to disable line wrapping altogether as already mentioned. With older versions of GNU `bc`, you can use `BC_LINE_LENGTH=9999` (or any value greater than the maximum size of the number you're expecting to see).

```
BC_LINE_LENGTH=9999 bc -l <<< 'scale=100;4*a(1)'
```

For other implementations, you could instead pipe to:

```
perl -pe 's/\\\n\z//'
```

or

```
sed -e :1 -e '/\\$/{N;s/\\\n//;b1' -e '}'
```

or

```
awk '{if (sub(/\\$/, "")) printf "%s", $0; else print}'
```

or (golf version):

```
awk '{ORS=sub(/\\$/,"")?"":RS};1'
```

Beware though that on some systems, text utilities don't support lines larger than some maximum (see `getconf LINE_MAX` which could be as low as 1024 bytes).

Comment: The `sed` version could be written as `sed -e ':1;/\\$/{N;s/\\\n//;b1}'`

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil, no that's not standard `sed` syntax. You can't have another command after the `:` or `b` command (in the original `sed` implementation, `;` is allowed in a label name) and you need a `;` before `}`. Yours would only work in the GNU implementation of `sed`.